# How to Insert checkbox value in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to Insert checkbox value in mysql using codeigniter?
Here I have 3 input checkboxes and in database table i have 3 columns for these checkboxes.

```
<label><input type="checkbox">a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">c</label>
```

If i click any of this checkbox and click the save button,i need to save the checkbox value as "true" in particular database columns.

Comment: dont ask for full code, please try something and the ask for help if you face some error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to create a array type checkbox name as follows **

```
<input type="checkbox" name="anything[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="anything[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="anything[]" value="3">
```

In Your controller you can get this by 
**$checkboxe_values = $this->input->post('anything')**

and do **print_r($checkboxe_values)** to see result for checkboxes

Comment: how to pass this particular value through ajax?and need to save to database?i have different database columns for these 3 checkboxes. . Each value should be inserted in seperate field (i.e. without using implode/explode functions). The best solution will be just passing "1" (if selected ) or "0" (if not selected). Please help me :) –

Comment: you can use these fields inside a form 
and then you have to do in jquery by ajax like this

data = new FormData($('#form_id_here')[0]);
$.ajax({ 
 type:"POST",        
 url:"call your controller method here",
 data:data,                
 mimeType: "multipart/form-data",        
 contentType: false,        
 cache: false,        
 processData: false,        
 success:function(data){  
     alert('operation success')        
 }      
});

and if you have again query if you share code i will do it for you

Comment: ok try this
chk1=0;
chk2=0;
chk3=0;
if ($("#chk1").prop("checked") == true){
 chk1 = 1;
}
if ($("#chk2").prop("checked") == true){
 chk2 = 1;
}
if ($("#chk3").prop("checked") == true){
 chk3 = 1;
}

AND CALL AJAX ON BUTTON CLICK or Form
$.ajax({ 
 type:"POST",        
 url:"call your controller method here",
 data:{chk1: 'chk1',chk2: chk2,chk3: chk3},                
 mimeType: "multipart/form-data",        
 contentType: false,        
 cache: false,        
 processData: false,        
 success:function(data){  
     alert('operation success')        
 }      
});

Comment: did  you cjanged the view like this
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="anything[]" >
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="anything[]" >
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk3" name="anything[]" >

OR

can you share whole code so i help you in a better way i am always here to help others.

Comment: <label><input name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkbox"  id="f1" type="checkbox">a</label>
<label><input name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkbox"  id="f2" type="checkbox">b</label>
<label><input name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkbox"  id="f3" type="checkbox">c</label>
<a id="Save"></a>

Comment: Your View ->

<label><input name="f1" class="chkbox" id="f1" type="checkbox">a</label> 
<label><input name="f2" class="chkbox" id="f2" type="checkbox">b</label> 
<label><input name="f3" class="chkbox" id="f3" type="checkbox">c</label> 

<button id="save">Save</button>

Comment: Your jquery -> 

$(document).ready(function () {var chk1=0; var chk2=0; var chk3=0;$('#save').click(function(){if($("#f1").prop("checked") == true){chk1 = 1; }if($("#f2").prop("checked") == true){ chk2 = 1; }if($("#f3").prop("checked") == true){ chk3 = 1; }$.ajax({type:"POST",url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/add_data') ?>",data:{f1: chk1,f2: chk2,f3: chk3},mimeType: "multipart/form-data",contentType: false,cache: false,processData: false,success:function(data){alert('operation success')}});});});

get values in controller
$f1 = $this->input->post('f1');
same for f2 and f3

Comment: its calling the controller but its not printing the value                                    $f1 = $this->input->post('f1'); 
  print_r($f1);

Comment: just print_r($this->input->post());

Comment: alert(chk1);alert(chk2);alert(chk3) 
just befaore ajax call and check values of checkboxes and let me know

Comment: ya.now its working fine.i gave like this $f1= $this->input->post('f1',TRUE);

Comment: if  i helped you then please mark this as answer and upvote
Thanking You

Comment: further help add me on Gmail on nirajpatel.mdl@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

> in View `<form>` set post method

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chknm[]" value="a">a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chknm[]" value="b">b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chknm[]" value="c">c</label>
```

> Controller

```
$values = $this->input->post('chknm');
print_r($values);
```